# Best practice to avoid InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified?

Tags: c#, .net

Very often I need something like that:

```
 foreach (Line line in lines)
 {
    if (line.FullfilsCertainConditions())
    {
       lines.Remove(line)
    }
 }
```

This does not work, because I always get a `InvalidOperationException` because the Enumerator was changed during the loop.

So I changed all my loops of this kind to the following:

```
List<Line> remove = new List<Line>();
foreach (Line line in lines)
{
   if (line.FullfilsCertainConditions())
   {
      remove.Add(line)
   }
}

foreach (Line line in remove) {
{
   lines.Remove(line);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is really the best way since in the worst case I have to iterate 2 times over the original list and so it needs time 2n instead of n.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I was able to do that using Mark's answer!But what if my collection doesn't implements RemoveAll()?

For example a

> System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection

EDIT 2:

Again with the help of Mark I'm now able to make the following call to remove all ScatterViewItems:

```
CollectionUtils.RemoveAll(manager.getWindow().IconDisplay.Items, elem => elem.GetType() == typeof(ScatterViewItem));
```

Comment: i got the same problem some time ago and no solution. It's even worse - it's not 2n but n^2 since `lines.Remove(line)` iterates again over the collection.

Comment: But O(2n) equals O(n) :-) really: In Java you can use an Iterator for doing this, or go for an Copy-on-Write Collection implementation which allows modifications while iterating.

Comment: @Marc Gravell THanks a lot! Unfortunaetly I can't upvote a second time!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is baked directly into `List<T>`:

```
lines.RemoveAll(line => line.FullfilsCertainConditions());
```

or in C# 2.0:

```
lines.RemoveAll(delegate(Line line) {
    return line.FullfilsCertainConditions();
});
```

---

In the non-`List<T>` case (your edit to the question), you could wrap this something like below (untested):

```
static class CollectionUtils
{
    public static void RemoveAll<T>(IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        while (count-- > 0)
        {
            if (predicate(list[count])) list.RemoveAt(count);
        }
    }
    public static void RemoveAll(IList list, Predicate<object> predicate)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        while (count-- > 0)
        {
            if (predicate(list[count])) list.RemoveAt(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Since `UIElementCollection` implements the (non-generic) `IList` this should work. And quite conveniently, with C# 3.0 you can add a `this` before `IList` / `IList<T>` and have it as an extension method. The only subtlety is that the parameter to the anon-method will be `object`, so you'll need to cast it away.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same in .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: @Matten - added a C# 2.0 example.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - very simple, very elegant. Thanks :)

Comment: @Matten - .NET 2.0 or C# 2.0? .NET 2.0 supports LINQ which is part of C# 3.0. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx

Comment: Just to be pedantic - you can use the top (lambda) version in C# 3.0 when targeting .NET 2.0; lambdas are (in this context, at least) a language feature, not a runtime one.

Comment: @Omar - .NET 2.0 doesn't *officially* support LINQ - but it can be hacked in with LinqBridge etc...

Comment: You can also simply use a for loop instead of a foreach loop. Then you're not involving an Enumerator in the first place.

Comment: @Omar - nice to know. But we're stuck with .NET 2.0 with no additional libraries, so C# 2.0 ... Maybe our company will some day update the machines, but...

Comment: @Omar: Don't confuse the framework and runtime versions. LINQ was part of .NET 3.5 (with C# 3) which runs on the same runtime as .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Marc - I will try it. We got VS2010 two months ago for a Sharepoint project but I did not use it for our old projects, yet

Comment: and you can use the C# 3.0 (or above) **compiler** to create apps that run on .NET 2.0, via multi-targetting. Then you get things like lambda support but it is still .NET 2.0

Comment: @Marc one thing remaining... should i put the line lines.RemoveAll(line => line.FullfilsCertainConditions()); into the foreach loop?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - in the example given, no

Comment: @Marc Gravell but then what is line referencing?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - `line` is the parameter name of an anonymous method you are writing. DeleteAll will do the loop internally, and *for each item* it will call that method (in this context, it might also be called a "predicate"). So on successive calls to the anon-method, `line` will contain the item from the list that the DeleteAll method was considering. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Thanks a lot, now I understand. But one last question. What if my collection doesn't implement RemoveAll()? (I also edited my question for that)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace original list with filtered one:

```
lines = lines.Where(line => line.FullfilsCertainConditions()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a new list instaed:

```
public IList<Line> GetListWithoutFullfilsCertainConditions(IList<Line> fullList) 
{
    IList<Line> resultList = new List<Line>(fullList.Count);

    foreach (Line line in fullList)
    {
       if (!line.FullfilsCertainConditions())
       {
          resultList.Add(line)
       }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can just use while loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < lines.Count)
{
  if (lines[i].FullfilsCertainConditions())
  {
     lines.RemoveAt(i);
  }
  else {i++;}
}
```