# iterating over a collection and removing ones I dont want

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-3.5

I have a problem with the following.  I have a collection:

```
Collection<Vehicle> list = new Collection<Vehicle>();

code = 1,2,3, Description = "aaa"
code = 10,438,13, Description = "bbb"
code = 81,8623,362, Description = "ccc"
code = 163,4312,53, Description = "ddd"
...
```

But I only care about some of them..  The list I care about is here, i.e. codesCareAbout = "1|2|3|163|4312|53"

I need to iterate through the collection and either deleting the Vehicle I don't care about, or cherry picking into another list containing the Vehicles I care about?

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
James

Comment: What is the datatype of code?

Comment: What is the type of the `code` property? Is it a string or a collection of some sort? (And `codesCareAbout` looks like a string to me; is that right?)

Comment: Related but not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718725/best-practice-to-avoid-invalidoperationexception-collection-was-modified

Comment: @Jose +1 - also, what is the datatype of `list`?  Here it looks like a hashtable of some sort, but the type is given as a collection of Vehicle objects.  Either way, I think this may involve some form of LINQ.

Comment: codesCareAbout is int[]  I also want to avoid having duplicates.. i.e..  notice codes 1, 2 and 3 are values I care about, but I only want one "aaa" is be within the list.

Comment: tried the following so far..  foreach(string code in codesIcareAbout)
            {
                var test = from facility in Vehicles
                           where facility.Code == code
                           select new MyObect(...) 

            }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate your list backwards, and use `RemoveAt` using the `for` index to remove from the list:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Foo item = list[i];

    if (IsFoobar(item))
        list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Counting backwards is required so that you don't mutate your index counting as you go, using a for loop is required because you cannot mutate a list being enumerated with an enumerator.

Alternatively, do as you suggested, populate into an empty list the stuff you want - however, usage depends on whether you need to modify the list you are given or can make a new list.

Comment: just to clarify, for this example to work Adam, what happens in IsFooBar?  Thanks,

Comment: @JamesRadford apologies, I've not answered your question about how to determine an item to remove, just how to remove it from a list in a fairly clean way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Vehicule has Code (string) property and Description property (question is not clear !).

1/ Clone the list : `var clone = list.ToList();`

2/ Iterate and decide if current item is interesting :

```
foreach(var item in clone)
{
   if (! IsInteresting(item))
      list.Remove(item);
}
```

3/ IsInteresting could be, for example :

```
foreach(var code in item.Code.Split(','))
{
    if (codesCareAbout.Split('|').Contains(code))
      return true;
}
```

Comment: ah sorry, kinda newish to Soverflow.. Have marked the others as answered :)

Comment: To mark as "answered", you must click on the green check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the list with linq produces the cleanest code:

```
var interestinglist = list.Where(v=> v.IsInteresting(v));
```

IsInteresting can be implemented as

```
codesIcareAbout.Intersect(v.Codes).Any();
```

this assumes both fields are collections rather than strings, but that is easily fixed with a call to string.Split().